# Why does my conversion with Magick.NET result in a black PCX file?

Tags: imagemagick, magick.net

I have following *.png*-file
[image]

which I want to convert with Magick.NET to a *.pcx*-file. I use following code for the conversion:

```
using System.Drawing;
using using ImageMagick;

using (var bitmap = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile("ptOHf.png"))
using (var magickImage = new MagickImage(bitmap))
{
  magickImage.Format = MagickFormat.Pcx;
  magickImage.ColorType = ColorType.Palette;
  magickImage.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.Gray;

  magickImage.Write("C:\\somefile.pcx");
}
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

Package used: [Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU 7.0.1.500](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU/7.0.1.500) (Net40)

Comment: Try adding `flatten` after opening since the whites in your image are actually in the alpha layer not the colour layer. Your image is actually entirely black, all the info is in the alpha layer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell oh, excellent catch - I'll try that - could you possibly provide some code as an answer (I would love to give you some points for that discovery) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really speak `.NET`, Dirk (@dlemstra) is the man for that, but the problem is that all the (white) information is actually in the alpha layer and the basic image itself is just solid black and ImageMagick has done that correctly as `PCX` cannot render transparency.

You can see what I mean if you extract the alpha layer like this:

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptOHf.png -alpha extract a.jpg
```

[image]

At the command line, you would make ImageMagick account for the alpha layer using `-flatten`

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptOHf.png -flatten result.pcx
```

I have no idea, but I guess in `.NET`, you would do something like:

```
using (var magickImage = new MagickImage(bitmap))
{
  magickImage.Flatten();
  magickImage.Format = MagickFormat.Pcx;
  magickImage.ColorType = ColorType.Palette;
  magickImage.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.Gray;
}
```

Comment: fyi: I did some research, and the easiest version to get this working is `magickImage.ColorAlpha(MagickColors.White);` - but your input totally saved my bacon today - thank you!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair You saved me so many hours of tireless research with a comment.